# PHP Excel Reader & Currency

Tags: php, excel

I'm using php excel reader for upload data to db from xls files.

I have a field with a currency ( € 245,78 ) and I can't read with my tool.

If I use this code:

```
$get_data_ab = utf8_encode($data->val(4,6,$sheet_def));
```

the result is:

```
¬ 246246246246.246246
```

If I use:

```
$get_data_ab = $data->val(4,6,$sheet_def);
```

the result is empty.

What is wrong? How can I charge the € values in a variable?

Comment: Hi Luca. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should add your correct solution as an answer and mark it as one. This is allowed and encouraged.

Comment: Oh thanks, ok il'do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many researches i found the fix method, i paste it here for who encounter the same problem.

The first thing to do is "add" a true value to the definition of the file:

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($nome_file,true);
```

After for read a custom number as € 245,78 you have to use this

```
$get_data_ab = number_format($data->raw(4, 6, $sheet_def), 2);
```

Hope it helps someone !